# How to use wpf 3D Engine in Windows phone app?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, windows-phone

Is there any way to use wpf 3D engine in windows phone application? I tried to add dlls to project but Icould not.

Comment: I guess WPF 3D engine is based on Direct 3D which also has native support on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Phone does not support the XAML-based 3D stuff that WPF supports.  To create a 3D graphics phone app, you have to use Direct3D and C++.

Comment: Here is (maybee useful) discussion about lack of high level 3d graphics support in WinRT: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/eb8085b6-5a48-4097-a367-fdbf1f27192f/uwphigh-level-winrt-3d-graphics-support?forum=wpdevelop